# My to do list in this React app doesn't appear

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks, state

Simple app. It just returns a `<ul>` of `<li>` elements.
Am I using `useState()` correctly? I had to use `Array.from()` before I could get the map function to work on `taskList`. Before that, I was getting an error saying that taskList.map is not a function.

Here's App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ToDoList from './components/ToDoList';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';

function App() {
  const [ tasks, setTasks ] = useState(['Test task', 'other task', 'blah task'])
  return (
    <>
      <ToDoList
        taskList={tasks}
         />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's TodoList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task';
import v4 from 'uuid';

export default function ToDoList(taskList) {
    const listItems = Array.from(taskList).map((task) => 
        <Task key={v4}
              detail={task} />
    );

    return(
        <ul>
            {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Here's Task.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Task(key, detail) {
    return ( // Number each item with keys... or an ol instead of ul
            <li key={key}>
                {detail}
            </li>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: here is a simple example to get you running https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-meadow-m87s9?file=/src/App.js. It maps an array from the state to li elements and includes a handler to append the state.

Not sure which error you are still having? Regarding your Array.from/state question, use state this way instead:

`[myState, setMyState ] = useState({list: ['item1', 'item2']})`

Then you can map over the tasks by simply doing `myState.list.map(item => ...)`

Comment: Now I'm getting taskList.list is undefined.

Comment: Ok, I've made you a code sandbox and edited the answer (also included how to append a new task, because that might be your next question)

Comment: That was definitely my next question!

Comment: :-) don't forget to upvote and approve the answer if it was useful